# How can one specify image path in JavaScript file without hardcoding whole path?

Tags: magento2, javascript

I'm using [webicon](https://github.com/icons8/webicon) script in my theme to use svg/png as icons. This is the code from my jQuery widget:

```
_create: function () {
    $(document).webicons({
        icons: {
            tile: 'http://magento2.dev:8888/project/pub/static/frontend/vendor/theme/en_US/images/tile.png',
            user: '../images/user.png'
        }
    });
}
```

If I hardcode the whole path the image displays correctly, second one doesn't display. I've tried other approaches that also wont display. Is there a way to do this directly in JS? I know I could load the path with  `data-mage-init` in PHP and pass it in with config options, but I'd like to know if anyone found a way to do this directly in JS?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is not a solution, but it is an explanation on why you SHOULD use the `data-mage-init` approach.
You kind of HAVE TO provide the calculated image paths via a template or something because of the theme fallback mechanism.
Also, if you provide the full path to something in the `pub/static` folder your widget will crash if the static resources are not deployed.
You need something that generates the image in `pub/static` before using it. passing it as a parameter from a template will ensure that.

Comment: Thanks Marius, it did do the trick, i passed the the url to static folder with: `data-mage-init='{"stickyFooter": {"baseUrl": "<?php echo $block->getViewFileUrl('images'); ?>"}}'` and prepended the url to '/user.png' in JS. Worked like a charm.

Comment: you should use `<?php echo $block->getViewFileUrl('images/user.png'); ?>` directly instead of appending `user.png` at the end because of the same fallback mechanism. The way you built it, if you change the theme and you have an `images` folder in your theme but not a `user.png` file, magento will not find the image and it will not fall back to the default theme/module